# How to configure Parse Server for Push Notifications

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I installed a Parse Server on my Ubuntu server which is hosted by Digital Ocean. I set it up using [this](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-parse-server-dashboard-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/) tutorial. I then added the dependencies to my android app and it connects perfectly. I can upload and retrieve data just fine.

In my case my app needs to know when a value has been changed in the database. I do not want to check the database every few seconds, which in my opinion is super dumb, inefficient and wasteful. I want to use the Push Notification feature but am stumped at how to set it up. I believe I have my Android app setup correctly, but I can't find any sense in the Parse documentation on how to setup the server side. For the most part I believe I need to set up the file according to [this](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#2-configure-parse-server) section. But it doesn't say where to save this file. I have looked hi and low and the file name `index.js` is often mentioned, but where do I find it. An `ls` in the home folder returns these files.

```
config.json logs nohup.out parse-dashboard-config.json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For listening changes on database, I recommend you to look at live query (https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android), instead of Push Notifications. Answering your question regarding push notifications, the file that you are trying to find is the config.json that you have in the tutorial that you followed.

Comment: Thanks, Davi, you are welcome to post that as an answer. I have been testing the ParseLiveQuery and it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot